# How do I know what UITextField the code is referring to?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have about 9 UITextFields in my XIB. In my code, when I will use the text fields, how will I know which text field my code is referring to. (This is important because I need to save it to a specific variable. I am using Xcode, if it helps. Should I put some identifier on the text field? Please help.

Comment: What does "make a pointer" mean? How were you thinking of doing that? How can you do it in such a way that you do _not_ know which text field it is?

Comment: It seems to me that when you "make a pointer" to a text field, the pointer will be referring to that text field.  If you want to know how to tell text fields (or any sort of UIView) apart, either keep track of which pointer points where, or make use of the (somewhat primitive) `tag` property.

Comment: Let me clear it up. I saw a code with a pinter to a UIButton, so I thought that it was also used for xib interfaces. I also edited the question a bit.

Comment: If you're talking about Interface Builder, it's a matter of which IB object you link to which program element.  (Not on a Mac right now and can't remember the terms.)  It's up to you to draw the lines appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I had to poke around on the web and I found a site where it told me to control+drag to the .h file under the @interface, and then control+drag element to the files owner. If anyone wants the link it is [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/how-to-collect-text-input-using-uitextfield/). It is for iOS but it works the same for mac (I hope.)